# .NET Core project reference issues - "Cannot find project info for 'XXX.csproj'"

Tags: c#, reference, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a *ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)* which targets *.NET Framework 4.5.2*.

After adding a reference to an empty class library of type 'Class Library (.NET Framework)', the following error appears:

> "Cannot find project info for 'XXX.csproj'. This can indicate a
>   missing project reference." Below you can see a screenshot of the
>   error.

This is my project file:

```
<Target Name="GenerateBuildDependencyFile" 
    DependsOnTargets="_DefaultMicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary" 
    BeforeTargets="_CheckForCompileOutputs" 
    Condition=" '$(GenerateDependencyFile)' == 'true'" 
    Inputs="$(ProjectAssetsFile)" 
    Outputs="$(ProjectDepsFilePath)"> 

<GenerateDepsFile ProjectPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath " 
                    AssetsFilePath="$(ProjectAssetsFile)" 
                    DepsFilePath="$(ProjectDepsFilePath)" 
                    TargetFramework="$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)" 
                    AssemblyName="$(AssemblyName)" 
                    AssemblyExtension="$(TargetExt)" 
                    AssemblyVersion="$(Version)" 
                    AssemblySatelliteAssemblies="@(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath)" 
                    ReferencePaths="@(ReferencePath)" 
                    ReferenceSatellitePaths="@(ReferenceSatellitePaths)" 
                    RuntimeIdentifier="$(RuntimeIdentifier)" 
                    PlatformLibraryName="$(MicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary)" 
                    CompilerOptions="@(DependencyFileCompilerOptions)"> 
</GenerateDepsFile> 
<ItemGroup>     
    <FileWrites Include="$(ProjectDepsFilePath)" Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDepsFilePath)')"/> 
</ItemGroup> 
</Target>
```

[Source of the project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERaDd.png)
I've searched the internet for a solution and found out that it could have something to do with transitive dependencies between projects. If A -> B -> C then A -> C. But I only have a *.NET Core* project and an empty class library.

Comment: Also had this problem some time ago, closing VS and doing a `dotnet restore` on the project fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I tried it out but sadly i still have the problem

Comment: Rather than showing a screenshot, please post the project file contents and error message as *text*. That makes it far, far easier to read, and more helpful for search engines.

Comment: I had a similar issue (but with .Net Core 2.0 as target platform), I have got the mentioned error when add new empty class library. Solution which was suggested by  jAC (dotnet restore), helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved this for me was changing target framework from 4.5.2 to 4.6.1 if anyone should encounter the same :)